# How to optimize a search query with multiple left joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My query works fine within the phpmyadmin. But, on the webpage, it takes about a minute to fetch the results. What will be the best approch to optimize it.

My query:

```
 $search = str_replace(",", "|", $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
    SELECT 
     table1.value2,
    
     table2.value2,
    
     table3.valueA,
     table3.valueB,
     table3.valueC,
     table3.valueD
     FROM table3
    
     LEFT JOIN table1
     ON table3.valueB= table1.value1
    
     LEFT JOIN table2
     ON table3.valueB = table2.value1
                             
     WHERE table3.valueA REGEXP '".$search."' 
     OR table3.valueB REGEXP '".$search."'
     OR table1.value2 REGEXP '".$search."' 
     OR table2.value2 REGEXP '".$search."'
     limit 10";
```

table3.valueB, table1.value1, and table2.value 1 are integers

table3.valueA, table3.valueC, table3.valueD, table1.value2, table2.value2 are varchar

Query can be anything for example:
Search --> Description of the search example

5321 -> numbers matching the id of a product

black shirt -> words matching the description of a product

shoes -> words matching the category of a product

Comment: I don't know what pattern you are trying to match via regexp, but most likely the search cannot use indexes, therefore will always be slow.

Comment: @Shadow I know that like is faster. but, I am trying to find a match even if it matches any code or word in a string. Will using wildcards with Like help? or is there a better solution to it?

Comment: Like will only be faster if you search for the beginning of the field content and the field is indexed. You can try to use fulltext indexing and fulltext searching instead of regexp.

Comment: Redesign the schema and UI so that either all the search columns are in a single table, or that you can deduce which table you should be searching.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection aside, there are several issues with the query.

First is the RegExp as explained in the comments. If you are using it just to provide search within multiple values, as it looks like from the replacing of `,` with `|` - don't - just use `IN`. If you really want more flexibility, look into using full text search with the `MATCH` function.

The next issue is the `OR` usage. You can get away with replacing the joins and ORs with `UNION`, so each of the fields uses an index.

Last, but not least, do not forget to run `EXPLAIN` on your queries, to see what and whether indexes are being used